# Difference between System.Windows.Controls.ListView and System.Windows.Forms.ListView?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms

I am noob .NET programmer so I tried to use ListView and display my items which I read from database. I tried to create column headers but the property Column is not available in System.Windows.Controls.ListView and it is in Forms.ListView.

Can somebody tell me that is the difference and which should I use where?

Should I use Controls.ListView or should I use Forms.ListView in WPF?

I want my app to be full WPF developed and avoid using WinForms. I want to have full control of the GUI interface and don't bother resizing WinForms with code and maths.

In the end I just want to display a read-only table data from database and it should be able to resize to full screen and backwards, with scrollbars, etc...

Comment: Everything in System.Windows.Forms is WinForms and shouldn't be used in a WPF app.

Comment: Yes, indeed a very basic question. I was in a hurry back then. I would delete the question but there are two answers. I will try to add more info maybe to make it specific to some sort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`System.Windows.Forms` is from WinForms and `System.Windows.Controls` is from WPF, so you should use `System.Windows.Controls.ListView`.

Answer (score 1):

In order to display a read-only table data from database in your WPF application you must use ItemSource.I will take a simple example of User entity with ID and Name proprety.

1. In the XAML view we add the ListView tag

   `<ListView x:Name="UserTableListView"/>`
2. Then we need to create the User Class(Entity)

   ```
   public class User
   {
     public int ID { get; set; } //Id Field with getter and setter
     public string Name { get; set; }//Name Field with getter and setter
   }
   ```
3. Then we create a method to fill our ListView with data

   ```
   /// <summary>
   /// This method fill our listview with the list of users  
   /// </summary>
   private void FillUsersListView()
   {

       //We take an example of creating 3 users 
       User user1 = new User { ID = 1, Name = "Bettaieb" };
       User user2 = new User { ID = 2, Name = "Jhon" };
       User user3 = new User { ID = 3, Name = "Alex" };

       //We create a user list to use it later on the listview
       List<User> user_list = new List<User>();
       //We add the 3 users to the user_list
       user_list.Add(user1);
       user_list.Add(user2);
       user_list.Add(user3);
       //Finnaly we set the itemsource of ListView
       UserTableListView.ItemsSource = user_list;
   }
   ```
4. We create columns of our ListView and we call the method "FillUsersListView()" to fill the data

   ```
       //We add the columns it must be similair to our User class
       gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
       {
           Header = "Id", //You can set here the title of column
           DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("ID") //The Biding value must be matched to our User Class proprety ID
       });
       gridView.Columns.Add(new GridViewColumn
       {
           Header = "Name",
           DisplayMemberBinding = new Binding("Name")//The Biding value must be matched to our User Class proprety Name
       });
       FillUsersListView(); //We call here the method in order to fill our listview with data!
   ```

**Happy Coding**